# Opening Python Interactive Tab in different Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, interactive, new-window

I was looking to move the "Interactive - #1" tab that pops up when you run a jupyter cell in VSC to a new window but was unable (for a second monitor). If I open a new window and drag the tab to it, the GUI changes like it will accept the tab but the tab fails to transfer after releasing the click as if nothing was prompted.

I also tried per the [Jupyter instructions on VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) to open an interactive window independently and then return to my python file and "*use the Jupyter: Run Current File in Python Interactive Window command from the Command Palette*", however, this always opens a new Interactive tab within the window it currently exists which remains untransferrable.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a developer on the Jupyter extension that provides the Interactive Window. The interactive window is supported by a custom editor that hosts a webview and the notebook interface. Unlike just a source file it has lots of backing data and connections going on with the host VS Code process. So we don't support this operation of dragging it to a new VS Code window. You'd have to actually run the interactive window in the new VS Code window instance. Sorry about that. If you would like, you could file this as an enhancement request on our github page here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues

Comment: Done, thanks for advice! https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5452

Answer (score 0):

Just open the settings page (File > Preferences > Settings), search for 'interactive window mode' and change the setting value to 'perFile. ' Now when you run cells from different files, they will each run on their own separate window.

Comment: I did this and restarted VSC, but when I run cells they still auto populate in the same window. I tried moving them to different windows and still had no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and you came across this question trying to prevent your jupyter cell output from scrolling on the page but allow you to view on a different pane instead, I just found out that you can adjust the settings by searching for `@tag:notebookOutputLayout` on your VS code settings.

Comment: not solving the issue OP has.