# Does VS code have variable explorer object like we have it in spyder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spyder

I will post the picture of what exactly I am asking variable explorer in spyder

[image: variable explorer in spyder]

So do we have this feature in VS code?

I tried a lot to find it on google but was unhappy to not find it.

Comment: Only when debugging, the Locals and Autos windows.

Comment: I didn't understand ?

Comment: Perhaps read this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64409231/11107541 ?

Answer (score 17):

1. **Open your .py script in vscode**
2. **Right click anywhere on the script > Run current File in interactive Window**

[image: RightClick]

3. **In the toolbar of the interactive window click on the variable icon**

[image: Interactive Window]

4. **You can  now consult the values of variables created by your script**

[image: Variable Explorer]

Comment: The values of variables displayed in JUPYTER:VARIABLES can not be copied to clipboard. a little frustrated. Do you know how to workaround it?

Comment: For me, before "Run current File in interactive Window" appeared as an option, I had only one option, which was to install jupyter (I forget what it said exactly), and then when I went back to right click anywhere in the script, the same options listed in number 2 appeared. Thanks for this trick!

Answer (score 4):

spyder is probably running a REPL (Jupyter is doing that also). From that python process they show the local and global variables, just like a debugger would do on a breakpoint.

If you use Python Interactive you have similar functionality with the [Variables Explorer and Data Viewer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_variables-explorer-and-data-viewer) or use [Jupyter notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_jupyter-notebooks)

Answer (score 1):

You can now find all variables in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code in the Output panel under **Jupyter: Variables**

[image: Jupyter: Variables]