# Variables inside functions are not showing in variable explorer

Tags: python, variables

[image]
*I am talking about dfselect in my case*

I am a beginner in python, now I have a school assignment. We define a lot of function to use in the main function. When I run the file everything works fine only the variables (big arrays in my case) are not showing up in the variable explorer, all the variables are inside the functions. Is it possible to let them show up in the variable explorer?

Comment: Are you talking about VS Code?

Comment: What is variable explorer?

Comment: I think this may be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409231/is-there-any-wayby-setting-or-extension-to-view-and-use-variables-in-vscode-ot but this is a feature I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @Barmar I think OP is using [`Spyder variable explorer`](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/3/variableexplorer.html)

Comment: Viewing local variables still probably requires setting a breakpoint inside the function, since they go away when the function finishes.