# Get the Python console in a VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

recently I switched from Spyder to VScode and I miss getting the output of python scripts in console. By that I mean:
Let's say I have a script as follow:

```
x = []
def append_func(x):
   for i in range(10):
      x.append(i)
   return x

y = append_func(x)
```

and when I ran that script in Spyder, `x` would be generated, `append_func` would be declared and `y` would be generated as well. Then in console (outside of the script) I would write:

```
sum(y)
len(x)
len(y)
```

and get informations that may interest me after running the script.

So I would like play with my variables that were generated inside the script without editing the script and rerunning it.
Similar functionality is in Matlab - whenever we run the script, all of the variables and functions defined in a script are accessible in console, so we can transform/calculate/reuse them, check how some variables look like or what are their types, (...).
It's very handy when the scripts has kinda long execution time and we want to check some statistics of variables we didn't think about before.

Is such functionality in VS Code?
Screen from Spyder. As we can see `x` and `y` got saved into memory and can be used in the console:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just python shell that has imported your script? Your script doesn't output anything

Comment: [This sounds like the answer to what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64437552/18505884)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way(by setting or extension) to view and use variables in VSCODE other than setting breakpoints. likes Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409231/is-there-any-wayby-setting-or-extension-to-view-and-use-variables-in-vscode-ot)

Comment: use the interactive Python, `#%%`, See the doc

Comment: highlight/select the code you want to "run" then hit `shift-enter`

Answer (score 3):

Please use the **python interactive**. There are two ways in vscode, one is *terminal* and the other is *window*.

Right-click and select `Run Current File in Interactive Window` to open an interactive window and run the current script. You can continue to enter python code in the input box below and execute it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a python interactive terminal, then select all the code in the file and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run code in the terminal, then you can continue to type python code and press Enter to execute.

[image]

If you want to look at the variables, clicking `Variables` in the interactive window will open a variables panel for you to look at.

[image]

*There are more detailed instructions in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).*

In addition, as you can see, there is a shortcut key conflict by default. If you want to use the shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open an interactive window, you need to modify the corresponding [shortcut key settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use python interactive option while right clicking on the vs code span area. it asks you to install jupyter install it and you are ready to use python console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).